# SonarQube: Users authentication during upgrade to 5.6

Tags: sonarqube

The upgrade guide (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.6+Upgrade+Notes) says to copy the sections related to the users authentication.

But when I do so, the call to /api/system/migrate_db returns 401. The UI sends me on the maintenance page (this is misleading, because I don't know if this is expected or not).

I have found that dropping the LDAP parameters from the sonar.properties allows me to start the migration. But then the migration fails..

Comment: The parameter preventing the migration was 

    sonar.forceAuthentication=true

Comment: Please add it as answer so I can upvote it, as this was exactly what happened to me today. Thanks.